# Package Manager console not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

According to this http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console I should see the PM prompt and commands like `get-packages`  should work. With my VS2010 the Package Manager Console prompt says

```
PS E:\myprojectfolder
```

and none of the commands work - it issues an error saying:

```
PS E:\project>  get-package -ListAvailable
The term 'get-package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is co
rrect and try again.
At line:1 char:12
+ get-package <<<<  -ListAvailable
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: restarting the computer and VS somehow fixed this issue, closing.

Comment: that was not issue, the problem was i didn't even see the PM prompt

Comment: Ah I see. Yes I've seen this issue before (where the NuGet module isn't loaded). We'll look into it.

Comment: This issue is on the [NuGet issue tracker](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1160), though it's closed (at the moment).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Rather than voting to close and leaving the answer in comments, it's worth posting it as an actual answer so that others with the problem see an answered question in search results, rather than an unanswered one :-)

Copied from the comments:

> restarting the computer and VS somehow fixed this issue, closing
>
> Yes I've seen this issue before (where the NuGet module isn't loaded)
>
> This issue is on the [NuGet issue tracker](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1160), though it's closed (at the moment)

Comment: Thanks. Restarting VS worked for me. As it's a problem loading NuGet module, this seems to be the most valid workaround.

Comment: It's a beta problem. Something with the powershell not loading nuget when creating a new project. It will be resolved in the Release Candidate.

Comment: This works for me sometimes, other times not.  I'm already at my 20th restart and are about to go insane.

Comment: This is relevant even to VS 2015. The Package Manager Console was displaying "Provider Failed" and not giving me a prompt. Only restarting my computer fixed it; restarting just VS did not.

Answer (score 33):

The solution to this problem would be:

1. Close the Package Manager Console
2. Close the Project
3. Close Visual Studio
4. Start Visual Studio
5. Open the project again

Answer (score 0):

I was using Package Manager Console for installing a package and was getting this error. Strangely by using the Nuget Package Manager UI did not generate this error and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

1. open visual sutido
2. open the package manager console
3. use the file menu open your project