# nuget package manager console not working, package source dropwdown is disabled and empty

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm new to asp.net, and I'm trying to run migrations, but I can't make the nuget console manager to work. I've installed everything:

- the .NET core
- Nuget package management extension

but I still can't work it out.

[image]

(the nuget.org source package is already installed and checked)

Comment: Are you debugging?

Comment: I don't know how to debug in visual studio I'm very new to this. Can you guide me through what I can do to see the error logs or something plz? @mxmissile

Comment: Mid-debugging might cause it to be disabled, only reason I mentioned it. What version of VS are we talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891966/package-manager-console-not-working

Comment: Ah, no I'm not debugging at the same time so I don't think that's the problem, by the way, the vs studio is v8.5 for mac. And I've already checked that question, I restarted my computer and vs studio and everything. (there is something though, the extention gets disabled each time I restart VS, I don't know if it's related somehow) thank you by the way. @mxmissile

Comment: What is `.NET framework 7`? Are you from some alternate future?

Comment: ah, hhhh no, I just heard someone in this community call .net framework core .net framework 7, that's all. so by 7 I mean .net framework core

Comment: Well I don't know who would call it that. That's extremely confusing, because .NET Core is not the same as .NET Framework. The latest version of .NET Core is 3, and the latest version of .NET Framework is 4, and the upcoming replacement for them both is called simply ".NET 5". I'd suggest not calling anything .NET Framework 7, that's just going to confuse everyone.